# Opens on vs Opens in

Tags: american-english, business-language

I have a service that deals with open hours of businesses.

People can browse the service and see if their favorite business is open right now and if not, when is the next time that it will be open.

If the place is open, we say

> Open now.

If the place is closed right now but will open in the next few minutes we say

> Opening in 45 minutes.

If the place will open later today we mention the exact time

> Opens at 2:00 pm.

And lastly, if for example it's Monday and the place will only be open in Wednesday, we say

> Opens in Wednesday at 2:00 pm.

My question is about the last case.

Should it be "Opens **in** Wednesday at 2:00 pm." or "Opens **on** Wednesday at 2:00 pm" or perhaps something else ?

Thanks!

Comment: The shop doesn't open _in_ Wednesday, but it _can_ open _in_ a specific month (it opens in March) or year (it opened in 2012). For days we use _on_.

Comment: Or if it regularly opens only on Wednesdays you could say *Opens on Wednesdays only*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Opens on", as perhaps you expect. You could just say "Opens Wednesday", possibly, but I don't like the omission much.

Comment: The form with "on" omitted is, however, more common—like it or not. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=open+on+Wednesday%2Copen+Wednesday&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Copen%20on%20Wednesday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copen%20Wednesday%3B%2Cc0  (although, oddly enough), the form with  "on" is more common with "Sunday"! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=open+on+Sunday%2Copen+Sunday&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Copen%20on%20Sunday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copen%20Sunday%3B%2Cc0